# How to replace text strings (by bulk) after getting the results by using grep

Tags: search, replace, grep

One of my Linux MySQL servers suffered from a crash. So I put back a backup, however this time the MySQL is running local (localhost) instead of remotely (IP-address).

Thanks to Stack Overflow users I found an excellent command to find the IP-address in all .php files in a given directory! The command I am using for this is:

```
 grep -r -l --include="*.php" "100.110.120.130" .
```

This outputs the necessary files with its location ofcourse. If it were less than 10 results, I would simply change them by hand obviously. However I received over 200 hits/results.

So now I want to know if there is a safe command which replaces the IP-address (example: 100.110.120.130) with the text "localhost" instead for all .php files in the given directory (/var/www/vhosts/) recursively.

And maybe, if only possible and not to much work, also output the changed lines to a file? I don't know if thats even possible.

Maybe someone can provide me with a working solution? To be honest, I dont dare to fool around out of the blue with this. Thats why I created a new thread.

Comment: Regardless of what solution you arrive at make a backup of the files beforehand.

Comment: Ofcourse. Stands for itself. But instead of restoring over and over, I rather do it correctly straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most standard way of replacing a string in multiple files would be to use a tool such as `sed`. The list of files you've obtained via `grep` could be read line by line (when output to a file) using a `while loop` in combination with `sed`.

```
$ grep -r -l --include="*.php" "100.110.120.130" . > list.txt
# this will output all matching files to list.txt
```

**Replacing IP in matched files**:

```
while read -r line ; do echo "$line" >> updated.txt ; sed -i 's/100.110.120.130/localhost/g' "${line}" ; done<list.txt
```

This will take `list.txt` and read it line by line to the `sed` command which should replace all occurrences of the IP to "localhost". The `echo` command directly before `sed` outputs all the filenames that will be modified into a file `updated.txt` (it isn't necessary though as `list.txt` contains the same exact filenames, although it could be used as a means of verification perhaps).

> To do a dry run before modifying all of the matched files remove the
>   `-i` from the `sed` command and it will print the output to `stdout`
>   instead of in-place modifying the files.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the help and detailed information. I tested it several times and it works. Though I had one issue where it didnt replace the IP, but maybe thats because of how the line was formulated?

It was like this: $link = mysql_connect("100.110.120.130:3306", $username, $password);

Weird. But it doesnt matter, as most of the results are replaced correctly. I will do the final few by hand. Thanks again I'L'I!

Comment: Oh and more thing; it only displays one changed line in "updated.txt", is that correct behaviour?

Comment: You're welcome! Hmmm strange about the one occurrence you mentioned won't match as it should've worked just like all the others. Which distro/version of `Linux` are you running? As for the "updated.txt" issue use two `>>` instead of one `>`, using one overwrites the file whereas two appends it - typo :/

Comment: You could try this as a test `echo '$link = mysql_connect("100.110.120.130:3306", $username, $password);' | sed 's/100.110.120.130/localhost/g'`. Do you get the same result, or does the IP get replaced with `localhost`?

Comment: Running CentOS 6 by the way. I will try it again tomorrow. Currently just left the dentist (and in pain). :S